# Dynamics 365 - Deployment Toolkit Error

Tags: sdk, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365-v9

I have been playing with developer toolkit for dynamics 365 in the last three days.

I am working on a simple plugin sample. For uncountable times I had to create a new Package, connect to CRM and add my plugin project once more to the packaged due to the following errors:
[image: .]

This error occurs when I try to deploy my plugin. Note that I am system administrator (No doubt about it)

When I try to open the CRM Explorer (View > CRM Explorer) or open my current crm connection through (Tools > Connect to Dynamics 365 Server) I get the error below:

[image]

I googled for hours on the internet without success. I really appreciate any clue of what is causing that issue.

Comment: Do you have installed the Report Authoring Extension? The developer toolkit doesn't get along very well with it...

Comment: I don't actually. This is a dev machine with only couple of tools installed.

Comment: What happens if you try to deploy the plugin to an v8.2 instance? It can be also related to v9 blocking TLS 1.0/1.1 https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4051700

Comment: I can't change the connection to try deploying in another environment.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be a CRM Deployment Administrator in order to deploy plugins to CRM that aren't registred in sandbox mode.  This is an actual AD permission:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crminthefield/2013/10/07/6-steps-to-add-a-deployment-administrator-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011/

Comment: Actually I am system administration. This is a trial instance where I have only one user which one I am using to login. As I told in the description. I have no doubt I am system administrator. Thanks anyway

Comment: So this is CRM online?  Are you registering it in Sandbox mode?

Comment: Yes, this is a trial instance of Dynamics 365 v9 and yes I am!

Comment: I'd try the plugin registration tool.  If that doesn't work, put a support ticket in with MS

Comment: It works fine through Plugin Registration Tool. As this is a trial environment, I don't think I am able to open a support ticket.

Comment: Try this URL: https://portal.office.com/support/support.aspx.  But since you can connect with the Plugin Registration tool, you must not be sending over the correct credentials.  May have to uninstall, and reinstall it.

Comment: I will try the URL you sent me. By the way, I have tried to uninstall then install again the Developer Toolkit and I had no lucky.